# Custom settings and custom meta data types

Tags: customsetting

Is custom setting and custom meta data types are deployed from sandbox 
to production  or we directly created them in the production ?

Please tell me how to deploy custom settings and custom metadata types into production from sandbox..Please mention syntax

Comment: Those can be deployed through changeset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom settings and Custom metadata types both can be deployed to production through Change sets.

To migrate data from Sandbox to production for Custom settings, use Dataloader.

Refer [Deploy Custom Metadata Types and Records to Production Orgs Using Change Sets](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_changesets.htm&type=0&language=en_US)

In case, if you need to import data into Custom metadata type, you need to use Custom Metadata Loader. Refer  [Load or Update Records with the Custom Metadata Loader](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_dataloader.htm&type=0)

Comment: Is it possible to deploy custom settings and custom metadata types through eclipse or force.com migration tool(ant)??

Comment: Yes. That's possible

Comment: How we can set the custom metadata types field values in package.xml or changeset ..Inorder to have them defautly in managed packages